# Why is this equation $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}k^2\frac{\lambda^k}{k!e^\lambda}=\lambda +\lambda^2$ true?

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series

Why is $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}k^2\frac{\lambda^k}{k!e^\lambda}=\lambda +\lambda^2$$

For the context: I am trying to calculate $E(X^2)$, where X is a poisson distributed random variable.

All my calculations lead to a dead end. Is there a trick to process the $k^2$? The only thing I see worth doing is pulling out $1/e^\lambda$.

Edit: Considering @Srivatsan's hint I got:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}k^2\frac{\lambda^k}{k!e^\lambda}=e^{-\lambda}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(k(k-1)+k)\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}=e^{-\lambda}\left( \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}k(k-1)\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}k\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}\right)$$
$$=e^{-\lambda}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}k(k-1)\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}+e^{-\lambda}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}k\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}=e^{-\lambda}\lambda^2\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{\lambda^{k-2}}{(k-2)!}+e^{-\lambda}\lambda\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\lambda^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}$$
$$=e^{-\lambda}\lambda^2\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}+e^{-\lambda}\lambda\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}$$
$$=\lambda^2+\lambda$$

And here we are! Thank you very much, @Srivatsan!

Comment: Related post: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44113/ (but not quite a duplicate).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*HINT:* Write $k^2 = k(k-1) + k$, and split the sum into two. [*Update:* The OP has added the complete solution to the post.]

---

If you are interested in a general $d^{th}$ moment of this distribution, then we are faced with an expression of the form
$$
\mathrm e^{-\lambda} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} k^d \frac{\lambda^k}{k!}. 
$$
To proceed, we first write $x^d$ as a linear combination of the $d$ [*falling factorial polynomials*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pochhammer_symbol)  (also called Pochhammer symbols): 
$$
\begin{align*}
(x)_1 &= x  
\\
(x)_2 &= x(x-1) 
\\
(x)_3 &= x(x-1)(x-2)
\\
&\vdots
\\
(x)_d &= x(x-1)(x-2) \cdots (x-d+1) 
\end{align*}
$$
[I am following the notation used in the wikipedia article.] After this step, the rest of the manipulations is very similar to the $d=2$ case that the OP showed in the question.

The falling factorial polynomials appear in multiple contexts. First, the Pochhammer symbol $(x)_i$ is obviously related to the binomial coefficient $\binom{x}{i}$. Further,  as seen above, these polynomials are very useful in manipulating summations. See also [this answer of robjohn](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/84062/how-to-find-this-generating-function/84081#84081).

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I'll try this out first. Then I'll come back if I need more help!

Comment: @Aufwind I have added some more notes to the answer.

Comment: Note: Sometimes people employ the reverse of wiki's notation. In other words, $(x)_n$ is taken to be $\prod\limits_{i=0}^{n-1}(x+i)$, while $x^{(n)}=n!\binom{x}{n}$. Be careful. :)

Comment: As a matter of fact, the polynomials these sums generate are called Bell polynomials. The formula is essentially the generalization of the usual [Dobinski formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DobinskisFormula.html) for Bell numbers, since $\mathrm{B}_k(1)=\mathrm{B}_k$.

Comment: @J.M. Thanks for the note. I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: In fact, the $d$th moment of the Poisson distribution is $\sum_{k=0}^n \lambda^k \left\{ n \atop k\right\}$, where $\left\{ n \atop k\right\}$ is a Stirling number of the second kind.  Thus in the special case $\lambda = 1$ we get that the $d$th moment is the $d$th Bell number.  See, for example, [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/6348/2370) to "Bell numbers and moments of the Poisson distribution" and the [Wikipedia article on the factorial moment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_moment).

Comment: @Mike, That's very nice. I will add these points to the answer and provide a link to your answer.

Comment: @all: You guys are awesome. I had only one simple question and I got so much worthful and interesting answers. Thanks! I have never seen this phenomenon more often as I have seen it here on math.stackexchange. Maybe it is a mathematician-related thing... :-)

Answer (score 1):

The moments of the Poisson distribution, as functions of the first moment, are given by the [Touchard polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Touchard_polynomials), also called "exponential polynomials".  Their coefficients are related to the enumeration of set partitions.  See [Dobinski's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dobinski%27s_formula).

Comment: Interesting; until this answer I hadn't realized that Bell polynomials and Touchard polynomials are precisely the same thing...